# Phonegap + jQuery Mobile + Stock / Line Chart

Tags: jquery, mobile, charts, cordova

Im trying found a solution for line/stock charts drwaing in phonegap application. Ive tried many libraries: amcharts JS, highcharts, but no one working.

Could somebody help me with this task? Any solutions are welcome. Platforms: Android, iOS.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same kind of problem. I created a JQuery mobile page with Google Visualizations. This seemed to work well in a browser. Then I used Phonegap to deploy it to Android and the charts did not work.
Reason for this turned out te be that the Android Webkit browser in earlier releases cannot handle SVG, and Google Visualizations was using SVG for the Charts.

I now use [JQPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) and the Charts work well on the Android/Phonegap version.

Answer (score 1):

check out [this link](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/). In this link plugins were available directly for drawing the graphs,pies,charts,bars etc...Hope it wil help you