# Mobile - best plugin for charts

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova, charts

Which is the best plugin to make charts with Cordova(Phonegap)?

(besides the jquery mobile plugin)

I have tried diferents, but on web pages, I don't know how works on mobile for example Flotr2 or HighChart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this answer: [Phonegap + jQuery Mobile + Stock / Line Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651984/phonegap-jquery-mobile-stock-line-chart)

And this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/7sX9b2dQLQg

I'd go with [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).

Answer (score 0):

**[ZoomCharts](https://zoomcharts.com/en/)** is a new chart and graph library, that brings JavaScript charts and graphs to both desktop and mobile and are very powerful and optimised.

[image]

With ZoomCharts you can create:

- timeline charts
- category charts (pie charts, facet charts)
- network graphs

and more.